# Angular using pipe from custom one

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I would be glad to get some help importing a build-in pipe to a custom one in angular 2.

This is my code :

```
@Pipe({ name: 'tablePipe' })

export class TablePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {

    }
    transform(field: any, format: Format, formatArg: string): any {
        let formattedField: any = ''
        switch (format) {
            case 'number':
                {
                    formattedField = this.decimalPipe.transform(field, formatArg);
                    break;
                }
        }
        return formattedField;
    }
}

export type Format = 'date' | 'string' | 'number';
```

and this is the error i got:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for DecimalPipe!

When importing regular custom  pipes in components, i am using :

```
@Component({
  ...,
  pipes: [MyCustomPipe],
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For this to work you need to add `DecimalPipe` to providers somewhere

For example

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [DecimalPipe],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can also add it to `providers` of a component (either the one where you 're using the pipe, or an ancestor component.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Please consider accepting my answer to indicate your problem is solved (clicking the white check mark below the up-down-vote button - thanks.